# Could not open input file: filename.php

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In .bat file contains code PHP filename.php I am getting error message after opening the bat file Could not find input file:filename.php . Can anyone give the suggestions please

```
private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string bat = "D:\\folder1\\file1.bat";
        if (File.Exists(bat))
        {
            if (radioButton1.Enabled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(bat.ToString());
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(bat);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: file1.bat contains only PHP filename.php

Comment: The path to filename.php is incomplete / wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing the process is not starting in the same folder as `filename.php`.  Either specify the full path in the bat file or set the startup folder:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = bat;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:\\folder1";  // or whatever is appropriate
process.Start();
```

Comment: Process not listed in my dropdown

Comment: Add `Using System.Diagnostics;` to the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for me. I got strucked in middle. You helped me a lot thanks!!!

Comment: how to display a message only when after process.start() completed?

Comment: If it doesn't run synchronously already (which I believe it should), then change your batch command to `START /WAIT PHP filename.php`